# How to call a parent class and instead create one of it's children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, object, model

I have a model directory structure like this:

```
/alerts
   base_alert.rb
   panic_alert.rb
   hardware_alert.rb

alert.rb
```

With the /alerts/x_alert.rb models setup like this:

```
class base_alert < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
end

class panic_alert < base_alert
    ...
end

class hardware_alert < base_alert
    ...
end

etc.
```

Is there any way to call create on alert.rb in the top directory, and, based on a parameter passed, it would create one of the children instead of alert.rb.

I.E.    Alert.create({type:"panic_alert"})

And it would create and return one of the panic_alert types of alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making few changes to the class definitions, like subclassing the `Alert` from `ActiveRecord::Base` rather than `BaseAlert`, you could achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

Following are the updated classes:

```
# app/models/alert.rb
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# app/models/alerts/base_alert.rb
module Alerts
  class BaseAlert < ::Alert

  end
end

# app/models/alerts/panic_alert.rb
module Alerts
  class PanicAlert < BaseAlert

  end  
end

# app/models/alerts/hardware_alert.rb
module Alerts
  class HardwareAlert < BaseAlert

  end
end
```

Following are few ways to create the subclasses from the base class:

```
@panic_alert = Alert.create!(
  type: 'Alerts::PanicAlert', #this has to be string
  #other attributes
) 

@alert = Alert.new
@alert.type = 'Alerts::PanicAlert' #this has to be string
# assign other attributes, if necessary
@alert.save 

@alert = Alert.new
@panic_alert = @alert.becomes(Alerts::PanicAlert) #this has to be class
# assign other attributes, if necessary
@panic_alert.save
```

Comment: This is the architecture I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/constantize) or the [safe_constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/safe_constantize) methods to do that. What they do is take a string and try to return the class the string refers to. For instance:

```
"BaseAlert".safe_constantize
=> BaseAlert
```

or

```
def method_name(alert_type)
  alert_type.safe_constantize.create()
end
```

The difference between the two is `constantize` will throw an error if there isn't a match for the string, while `safe_constantize` will just return `nil`. Remember, if you pass in a underscored string (say `panic_alert`) then you would have to [camelize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize) it.

Answer (score 0):

What seems like a lifetime ago I created [StiFactory](https://github.com/arvanasse/sti_factory) for this.  That said, I don't find much use for STI these days (hence the lack of maintenance).